# My emulator is not working properly

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I am running an application on my emulator, it is starting properly but in the end the activity manager is throwing the following error. Why is it throwing this error?:

```
ActivityManager: - exec '/system/bin/sh' failed: Accessing a corrupted shared library (80) -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild the emulator. It works for me as a catch-all for most things.

Answer (score 2):

recreate another new emulator. it works...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your emulator has been corrupted. Try deleting and re-creating the emulator using the AVD manager.